# libsqlite3.so loading on Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to replace `libsqlite3` with the special version for Python.
I have a special version of `libsqlite3.so.0 /path/to/libsqlite3.so.0` and configured `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
However, python's internal will not load it.

I checked and noticed the following:

1. `import sqlite3` loads python's original `/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite/__init__.py` and `dbapi2.py`.
2. `dbapi2.py` imports `_sqlite`, and this indicates `/usr/lib/python2.7//lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so`.
3. `_sqlite3.so` always loads `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0`, in spite of setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
4. If I copy `libpthread.so.0` to `/path/to/libpthread.so.0`, `_sqlite3.so` loads it. So, `/path/to/libpthread.so.0` is loaded but `/path/to/libsqlite3.so.0` is not loaded.

I want to know how to load `/path/to/libsqlite3.so.0`, a special version, without replacing `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0` (only with non-privileged permission).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try to force loading of the lib with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libsqlite3.so.0 python ...
```

The library will be loaded in memory when python will be executed. So normally when `_sqlite3` module will be imported, it will not load libsqlite3.so.0, and use the version already preloaded in memory.

**Edit**

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work in that case cause libsqlite3.so.0 is loaded by _sqlite.so module, loaded by dlopen() within Python. In that case, the manpage of dlopen() said that the order is:

1. (ELF only) If the executable file for the calling program contains a DT_RPATH tag, and does not contain a DT_RUNPATH  tag, then the directories listed in the DT_RPATH tag are searched.
2. If, at the time that the program was started, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH was defined to contain a colon-separated list of directories, then these are searched.  (As a security measure this variable is ignored for set-user-ID  and set-group-ID programs.)
3. ...

So if an DT_RPATH is set on the binary, it will be taken prior to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Thanks, it works but do I have to use LD_PRELOAD? Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH will work to replace libpthread.so.0 but not to replace libsqlite3.so.0. I'm bothered by this fact. What is the difference between two libraries?

Comment: libpthread.so.0 is loaded by python itself (check ``ldd /usr/bin/python2.7)`` while libsqlite3.so.0 is loaded by _sqlite.so, loaded itself by dlopen() in Python. I don't know why LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work in that case. Maybe cause of rpath in _sqlite.so ?

Comment: That's cause of the rpath, check the manpage of dlopen(), the priority order is explained: 1. rpath, 2. LD_LIBRARY_PATH, 3. runpath, ...

Comment: I succeeded to load my original one with only setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, by copying _sqlite3.so to /path/to and chrpath --delete /path/to/_sqlite3.so to remove rpath information from it. So many thanks to you!