# Python SQLite3 undefined symbol: OnUpdateString

Tags: python, sqlite

Using Debian 10, Python2.7.16 and try to

```
import sqlite3
```

But I receive this error message:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlite3.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateString
```

I installed the following packages (apt list --installed | grep sqlite):

```
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3/stable,now 1.6.1-4 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
libsqlite0/stable,now 2.8.17-15 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
libsqlite3-0/stable,now 3.27.2-3+deb10u1 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
php-sqlite3/stable,now 2:7.3+69 all  [installiert]
php7.3-sqlite3/stable,now 7.3.29-1~deb10u1 i386  [installiert]
python-pysqlite1.1/stable,now 1.1.8a-8 i386  [installiert]
python-pysqlite2/stable,now 2.7.0-1 i386  [installiert]
sqlite3/stable,now 3.27.2-3+deb10u1 i386  [installiert]
sqlite/stable,now 2.8.17-15 i386  [installiert]
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Clean Debian 10 is fine as one might expect.

```
$ docker run --rm debian:10 bash -c \
  "apt update && apt install -y python && python -c \
    'import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version_info)' && bash"
...
(3, 27, 2)
```

`python` (version 2, whose upstream reached end-of-life more than a year ago, by the way) package depends on `libsqlite3-0` via `libpython2.7-stdlib`. And its shared object file should have nothing to do with PHP.

```sh
# dpkg -L libsqlite3-0 | grep .so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
```

You may try to temporarily workaround with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 python your_script.py` (unless it's already loaded by something else, more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9315095/2072035)), but I guess your Debian is broken and needs to be reinstalled, because I installed SQLite-related packages you listed above and `python -c 'import sqlite3'` still works just fine.